# How would I go about creating parent/child records on a custom object?

Tags: lightning, custom-object, parent-to-child

I'm trying to import a list of grant awardees. I have a custom object called Grant, in which I will import all of the various grants (Grant A, Grant B, Grant C, etc.).

I could create a custom object called Grantees, in which I could import all of the grant awardees (North Side School Corporation and South Side School Corporation both received Grant A, etc.). But each of these grantees also have multiple sites to which they will disperse their funds (North Side School Corporation has 3 sites: North Side Elementary, North Side Middle, and North Side High School).

How would I indicate that all 3 of those child sites are receiving funds from Grant A, which was awarded to the applicant North Side School Corp?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need more than two objects, which is probably where your confusion lies. You'll want to read about [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), a database concept where we normalize data such that there are no nested tables. One way we could do this is by having four tables: Grant, Organization, Site, and Grantee.

Organization and Site can actually be represented by a single table, namely the Account object (either the built-in one, or a custom one). The Grantee object would have a link to the Grant and Site objects, at minimum, possibly with DLRS (Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary) to roll up the grants to the ultimate parent in the relationship, or as a third field to be filled out by a trigger or other automation.

You could also organize this as Grants, Organizations/Sites, Grantees, Disbursements, where the Grantee has a link to Grants and Organizations, and Disbursements has a link to Grantee and Site. You can do whichever you feel is more appropriate for your model, these are just some suggestions.